# php mysql multiple upload last insert id for loop

Tags: php, mysql

I am inserting input form into two different tables. the first table is for the information, and the other table is for images of the information.

When I submit the information, I would like to upload multiple images per a row of the first table in separate table, and also insert last_insert_id  to each images into the second table.

```
table1
location ID | address | contact information 

table2
pictureID | location ID | filepath
```

With the following code, it only inserts one image, but it uploads all the images into the folder.

```
<?php 

    include_once 'dbconnect.php';
    mysql_query("SET NAMES UTF8");
    session_start();
    $tbl_name="location";
    $tbl_image="image";

    if(isset($_POST['btn-upload'])){

        $name2=$_POST['name2'];
        $phone=$_POST['phone'];
        $email=$_POST['email'];
        $type=$_POST['type'];
        $other=$_POST['other'];
        $description=$_POST['description'];
        $address=$_POST['address'];
        $name=$_POST['name'];
        $lat=$_POST['lat'];
        $lng=$_POST['lng'];
        $country=$_POST['country'];
        $administrative_area_level_1=$_POST['administrative_area_level_1'];
        $place_id=$_POST['place_id'];
        $url=$_POST['url'];
        $website=$_POST['website'];




    $sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name(name2, phone, email, type, other, description, address, name, lat, lng, country, administrative_area_level_1, place_id, url, website) VALUES ('$name2', '$phone', '$email', '$type','$other', '$description', '$address', '$name', '$lat', '$lng', '$country', '$administrative_area_level_1', '$place_id', '$url', '$website')";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);

        for($i=0; $i<count($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']); $i++)
        {
            $file = rand(1000,100000)."-".$_FILES['image']['name'][$i];
            $file_loc = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][$i];
            $file_size = $_FILES['image']['size'][$i];
            $file_type = $_FILES['image']['type'][$i];
            $folder="uploads/";

            // new file size in KB
            $new_size = $file_size/1024;  
            // new file size in KB

            // make file name in lower case
            $new_file_name = strtolower($file);
            // make file name in lower case

            $final_file=str_replace(' ','-',$new_file_name);
            $res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE userId=".$_SESSION['user']);
            $userRow=mysql_fetch_array($res);
            $userID=$userRow['userID'];

            if(move_uploaded_file($file_loc,$folder.$final_file))
            {
                $sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_image(user_ID, Location_ID, file) VALUES('$userID', LAST_INSERT_ID(), '$final_file')";
                mysql_query($sql);
                ?>
                <script>
                alert('successfully uploaded');
                window.location.href='index.php?success';
                </script>
                <?php
            }
            else
            {
                ?>
                <script>
                alert('error while uploading file');
                window.location.href='index.php?fail';
                </script>
                <?php
            }

        }

        if($result){
        echo "Successful";
        echo "<BR>";
        echo "<a href='index.php'>Back to main page</a>";
        }

        else {
        echo "ERROR";
        }

        if($result1){
        echo "Upload Successful";
        echo "<BR>";
        echo "<a href='locationform.php'>Back to main page</a>";
        }

        else {
        echo "ERROR";
        }


    }   




?> 

<?php 
// close connection 
mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: Your code is right but after first successful image table insertion you are redirecting code. so you get only one insert in image table.

Comment: As mysql_* was deprecated in PHP 5.5 (please refer to [PHP doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)) you should **really** consider using [PPS : Prepared Parameterized Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). This will help [Preventing SQL injection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). **NEVER** trust user's data! And please use `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` on top of your pages and let us know if any error is thrown

Comment: Moreover, you should not assume that your sql calls are successful. Add error handling after each of the sql queries and print out any error messages

Comment: then how do I not to redirect the code?

Answer (score 0):

```
$b=$pdo->prepare(" INSERT INTO `table1` SET `address`=:address, `contact`=:contact ");
$b->bindParam(":address",$address);
$b->bindParam(":contact",$contact);
$b->execute();
$LastId = $pdo->lastInsertId();

if($LastId > 0){
    $b=$pdo->prepare(" INSERT INTO `table2` SET `pictureID`=:pictureID, `filepath`=:filepath ");
    $b->bindParam(":pictureID",$LastId);
    $b->bindParam(":filepath",$filepath);
    $b->execute();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out at last. It was the last_insert_ID that had a problem. Last_instert_ID had to be stated outside the For loop.

```
$locationID=mysql_insert_id($conn);
```

Above is added right below the first insert query.

```
$sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_location(name2, phone, email, type, other, description, address, name, lat, lng, country, administrative_area_level_1, place_id, url, website) 
    VALUES ('$name2', '$phone', '$email', '$type','$other', '$description', '$address', '$name', '$lat', '$lng', '$country', '$administrative_area_level_1', '$place_id', '$url', '$website')";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);

    $locationID=mysql_insert_id($conn);

    for($i=0; $i<count($_FILES['image']['name']); $i++)
    {
        $file = rand(1000,100000)."-".$_FILES['image']['name'][$i];
        $file_loc = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][$i];
        $file_size = $_FILES['image']['size'][$i];
        $file_type = $_FILES['image']['type'][$i];
        $folder="uploads/";

        // new file size in KB
        $new_size = $file_size/1024;  
        // new file size in KB

        // make file name in lower case
        $new_file_name = strtolower($file);
        // make file name in lower case

        $final_file=str_replace(' ','-',$new_file_name);
        $res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE userId=".$_SESSION['user']);
        $userRow=mysql_fetch_array($res);
        $userID=$userRow['userID'];


        if(move_uploaded_file($file_loc,$folder.$final_file))
        {
            $sql2="INSERT INTO $tbl_image(user_ID, Location_ID, file) VALUES('$userID', '$locationID', '$final_file')";
            $result = mysql_query($sql2);
            ?>
            <script>
            alert('successfully uploaded');
            window.location.href='index.php?success';
            </script>
            <?php
        }
        else
        {
            ?>
            <script>
            alert('error while uploading file');
            window.location.href='index.php?fail';
            </script>
            <?php
        }

    }
```

Answer (score -2):

```html
// how to upload multiple image in database but image save in folder with upload table with last insert id with loop //


table1  - table1
ID | field1 | field2 

table2  - upload
pictureID | ID | uploadimage 


<?php

include("config.php");


if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$field1 =$_POST['field1'];
$field2 =$_POST['field2'];
  
$sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO table1(field1,field2) VALUES ('field1','field2')"); // insert  record table 1



if($sql){
 $last = mysql_insert_id();   } 
if(isset($_FILES['uploadimage']['name']))  // uploadimage  file name and table column name same used here
{
    $file_name_all="";
    for($i=0; $i<count($_FILES['uploadimage']['name']); $i++) 
    {
        $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['uploadimage']['tmp_name'][$i];    
        if ($tmpFilePath != "")
        {    
           $path = "uploadimages/"; // create folder name
           $name = $_FILES['uploadimage']['name'][$i];
           $size = $_FILES['uploadimage']['size'][$i];

           list($txt, $ext) = explode(".", $name);
           $file= time().substr(str_replace(" ", "_", $txt), 0);
           $info = pathinfo($file);
           $filename ='image'. $file.".".$ext;
       }
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadimage']['tmp_name'][$i], $path.$filename)) 
           { 
             $sql_image=mysql_query("insert into upload(ID,uploadimage) values('".$last."','".$filename."')"); //insert record table 2(upload)

           }
    }
   
}
}
?>
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label>field - 1</label><input type="text" name="field1">
<label>field - 2</label><input type="text" name="field2">
<label>mutiple image upload</label> <input id="uploadimage" type="file" name="uploadimage[]" multiple accept="image/*" />
<button type="submit" name="submit">submit</button>
  </form>
```

Comment: You need to explain your answer